# How to represent serialized fields in ActiveRecord::Base in ActiveRecord:Migration (Rails 2.3.16)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new in rails. I read rencently how to serialize an array of string for example to store it in database.

```
class Fle < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialze :etat_fle

end
```

But i don't know how to represent this serialized field in the corresponding ActiveRecord::Migration
Have someone an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Major Major said, i have to declare the field like this in my migration file

```
t.column :type_fle, :text
```

and additionnaly i have to declare the field prefixed by the word *serialize* in my ActiveRecord::Base file

```
serialize :type_fle
```

Answer (score 2):

Store it as a `text`. If the table is already created -

```
add_column :table, :column, :text
```

Comment: thank u Major for your response. In my case the table is not created yet. Will your suggestion work in this case ?

Comment: Yes, when you generate your migration just give the variable a text type. So when you generate your migration you can use `column_name:text`, or if you're manually creating your migration use `t.text :column_name`